# How to Show Latest Uploded Post first Using SQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, content-management-system

I have a website where I show the post update on the database and we use PHP and SQL for that but currently oldest posts are showing first instead **I want to show the latest uploaded Post first.**

Here is My PHP code with SQL Query

```
$projectcat_query=mysql_query("select * from projectcat where id=3 ");
  while($projectcat_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($projectcat_query))
       { $catid=$projectcat_data['id'];
         $limit=3;
          $project_query=mysql_query("select * from projects where catid=$catid and status=1 limit $limit ");
          while($project_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($project_query)) { ?>
    <div class="item <?php echo $projectcat_data['name']; ?>">
        <div class="picframe">
            <a class="" href="project/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',$project_data['title']); ?>">
                <span class="overlay">
                    <span class="pf_text">
                        <span class="project-name"> <?php echo $project_data['title']; ?></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <img src="images/services/<?php echo $project_data['image']; ?> ">
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

and here my DB table looks like[image]

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding, so **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your 2nd query like this

```
$project_query=mysql_query("select * from projects where catid=$catid and status=1 order by id desc limit $limit ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add [ORDER BY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) statement to your query like this:

```
 $projectcat_query=mysql_query("select * from projectcat where id=3 ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: ORDER BY has to work, are you sure that you added it to a correct query?

Comment: ORDER BY makes sense but this is for the wrong query. You should add ORDER BY id DESC to your second query